# Javascript Unit Testing with function parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function calculatePrice(base_cost, base_dist, additional_cost, additional_dist, total_dist) {

  if (total_dist > base_dist) {



  } else {
     return base_cost;
  }


}

function unitTest() {
  var cost;

  cost = calculatePrice(10,20,5,5,15);
  if (cost != 10) console.log ("FAILED 1");

  cost = calculatePrice(10,10,5,5,15);
  if (cost != 15) console.log ("FAILED 2");

  cost = calculatePrice(20,10,5,1,15);
  if (cost != 45) console.log ("FAILED 3");

  cost = calculatePrice(20,10,5,1,1);
  if (cost != 20) console.log ("FAILED 4");

  cost = calculatePrice(10,10,5,1,14);
  if (cost != 30) console.log ("FAILED 5");

  cost = calculatePrice(10,10,5,2,14);
  if (cost != 20) console.log ("FAILED 6");

  console.log('Test complete');

}
```

I want to calculate the function value of unitTest for passing.I pass only 1 and need to write some pass code in the calculatePrice function.
Thanks a lot

Comment: can you explain bit more

Comment: I want to pass all the costs value in the unitTest function

Comment: I need to write in the calcutePrice function for passing unitTest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Math.ceil`

Calculation will be like that

```
var dist_diff = total_dist - base_dist;
var time = Math.ceil(dist_diff / additional_dist);
return (time * additional_cost) + base_cost;
```

So, you will got the Test complete result with no errors.